# How to avoid expansion (or protect text) in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I'm using a timestamp plugin for Vim that when you include

```
% Created: TIMESTAMP
% Modified: TIMESTAMP
```

in a file, replaces `TIMESTAMP` by the date of creation/modification. The problem is that I want to create a shortcut in my .vimrc to press `ts` in normal mode to do this with new files.

But of course, because I use Vim to edit this file, it is replacing `TIMESTAMP` by the date in .vimrc. How can I "protect" that text in my `nmap` definition, or at define the shortcut some other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
nnoremap        ts iTIME<C-\><C-o>iSTAMP<Esc>
nnoremap <expr> ts "iTIME"."STAMP\e"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an exception on filenames.

```
if expand('%') !~ 'vimrc\|....'
   s/TIMESTAMP/\=strftime('%')/g
```

Comment: Hi Luc, thanks for the answer. I didn't quite understand. Do you mean to put this in my .vimrc, or to change the plugin?

Comment: I don't know the plugin. If it hasn't planned for this kind of feature, you'll have to patch it.